# Forward inbound traffic from an interface to a docker container

Tags: docker, ip, nat

I have to forward the traffic having source `192.168.72.0/28` from `eth0` of my machine to a container running on the same machine having address `172.7.0.4` and running in `bridge` mode.

I have tried adding a routing rule

```
ip route add 192.168.72.0/28 via 172.17.0.4
```

I can see the traffic at the interface `eth0` but I cannot see at the interface of the Docker container.

I have also tried to DNAT'ing but w/o any luck

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -s 192.168.72.0/28 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.4
```

What am I missing?

The problem is that the container is running in the bridge and I do have the network interface which being a veth has a non standard name. In this case usually which is the approach?

Comment: What operating system are you running? How are you running the docker image? Who is your Firewalld backend?

Comment: You should read this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/

Comment: @A.B Yeah I've read but I do not think the solution will be using the `DOCKER-USER` iptables chain.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to achieve is making the machine a router and direct incoming traffic to the Docker container. 

The packet arrives to the `eth0` interface with src addr `192.168.72.2`. I would need to forward to the container interface having ip addr `172.17.0.4`. A `DNAT` would change the destination address so it's wrong.

Then I've tried `iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -s 192.168.100.0/28 -j ACCEPT` but in the iptables stats I see `0` and the packet DROP counter increase so something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Another attempt I've made was to create a new route table 
`ip rule add from 192.168.72.0/28 table connect` then add the default rule to this table `default via 172.17.0.4 dev docker0` so that a packet having source address `192.168.72.0/28` would be forwarded via `172.17.0.4`. However I can't see any packets  arriving to the container.

Comment: My guess is that this should be done through Docker so it installs itself the correct rules. `--expose` & co.

Comment: yeah I thought to that but i do not need to really expose any ports here so I can't see how expose should work here.

Comment: I have found the solution and I will share it.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new route table under `/etc/iproute2/rf_tables` appending `2 connect`

Then run the commands:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.72.0/28 table connect
ip route add default via 172.17.0.4 table connect
```

where `172.17.0.4` is the IP of the Docker container. In your case might be different.

then it's time to play with `iptables` rule

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.72.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -d 192.168.72.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.72.0/28 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 192.168.72.0/28 -j ACCEPT
```

At this point all the traffic  will go through the Docker container and it works.